# Count the number of occurences of every group of numbers in a line

Tags: text-processing

I now understand that a similar question has been asked, but not everyone might come to the adapted solution for this version of the question straight away.

Is there a simple way to count the number of occurrences of every group of numbers in a string? I can't think of one and anything I can think of seems way too convoluted, for what seems like a simple ish task.

(note that any string of numbers in the line could be any length)

Example input:

```
AGTHDTGY35AHSJFHHFG7GHHAHH
```

Example output:

```
2
```

Comment: (with a pattern like `[0-9]+` or `\d+`)

Comment: huh, I hadn't thought of that, which means perhaps worth keeping up as a separate question. so awk -F '[0-9]+' '{ print NF - 1 }'

Comment: just tested it, and yeah that works well

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in a Perl-ish way as shown:

```
$ perl -lpe '$_ = s/\d+//g'
  2
```